# Java: Setting one ImageIcon equal to another

Tags: java, variables, arguments, imageicon

I'm trying to make xpic equal to vpic just like in the example below. When I try to compile this code I get the error : "The local variable xpic may not have been initialized"

```
ImageIcon xpic;
ImageIcon vpic;

    vpic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Images/picture.png"));     
    vpic = xpic;
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? What do you mean by, `"It doesn't seem to work"`? And what do you mean by `"... to be able to inherit the same arguments as other ImageIcon variables."`? Please consider [editing your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24582046/edit), and if you do, please do so with our perspective in mind: folks who have no clue as to what you're trying to do, what your code looks like, and what problems you might be having.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that you have a typo because your code sets the vpic variable's reference, and then completely ignores what you set it to, and tries to set it to xpic (which is likely a `null` reference).

In essence, what you're doing is equivalent to this:

```
// both Strings are null
String str1; 
String str2; 

// assign a String object to str1:
str1 = "Hello";

// but then ignore and in fact discard the String object, and 
// re-set str1 to null by assigning it str2
str1 = str2; //????
```

You might want to change

```
vpic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Images/picture.png"));     
vpic = xpic;
```

to

```
vpic = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Images/picture.png"));     
xpic = vpic;
```